# zalenium java null pointer exception

Tags: java, selenium, testng, zalenium

im using zalenium for a remote driver but when i invoke the url the browser open and then trows a java null pointer exception

y tried to change the capabilities

```
public void GetInvoicing() throws MalformedURLException
{
   System.out.println("launching chrome browser"); 
   DesiredCapabilities capability = DesiredCapabilities.chrome();
   ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    //options.addArguments("headless");
    options.merge(capability);
   RemoteWebDriver driver = new RemoteWebDriver (new URL("https://zalenium.payclip.com/wd/hub"),capability);
   driver.get(baseUrl);
}

  @Test(priority=1)
  public void Test1() throws Exception {
  GetInvoicing();


driver.findElement(By.name("username")).sendKeys("santiago.galicia");
driver.close();
    }
```

the error that i get is the next

`FAILED: Test1
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at InvoicingDashboard.TestCases.Test1(TestCases.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:580)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:716)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:988)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:450)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:415)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:364)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:84)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1208)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1137)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1049)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1017)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:114)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)`

===============================================
    Default test

## Tests run: 1, Failures: 1, Skips: 0